# " EGL context not set " Error Occurs while generating local SDP offer on android Webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc

**Can you please check where i went wrong . Below is the method in which i was setting setVideoHwAccelerationOptions .**

```
public void setCamera() {

    factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    localMS = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");

    if (pcParams.videoCallEnabled) {

        getVideoCapturer();

        videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
        videoCapturer.startCapture(pcParams.videoWidth, pcParams.videoHeight, pcParams.videoFps);
        videoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", videoSource);
        videoTrack.setEnabled(true);

        localMS.addTrack(videoTrack);

    }

    audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
    audioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource);
    localMS.addTrack(audioTrack);

    mListener.onLocalStream(localMS, true);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have pass proper EGL context to PeerConnectionFactory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions before calling PeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource.

Below is code for that.

```
factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
localMS = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");

if (pcParams.videoCallEnabled) {

    getVideoCapturer();

    videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
    videoCapturer.startCapture(pcParams.videoWidth, pcParams.videoHeight, pcParams.videoFps);
    videoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", videoSource);
    videoTrack.setEnabled(true);

    localMS.addTrack(videoTrack);

}

audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
audioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource);
localMS.addTrack(audioTrack);

mListener.onLocalStream(localMS, true);
```

Eglcontext is created on the activity where your SurfaceViewRenderer is created. and it is passed as an argument to setVideoHwAccelerationOptions method.

below line shows how to create an EGL context .

```
rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
```

Please refer to below link for details: https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo